# Change default app for magnet links in Safari

Tags: safari

Currently Safari opens magnet links in Bittorrent. I'm moving to Deluge and I want to change the association.

I can't find anything in the preferences of either program to change the association, but I thought that it would be somewhere in **com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist**. Searching that plist file, I can't find any mention of magnets or bittorrent...

Where is this association recorded and how can I change it?

Answer (score 9):

I use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to change things  such as this when there is not a direct preference that can be set in a given app.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I saw that app and it looks good but I'm also curious to know how to do it manually. If I can't get an answer on that I'll probably go with this solution.

Comment: Still works under Mavericks

Comment: Nice recommendation!  A friend of mine needed this - Thanks

Comment: You're right ;) was pretty busy at the time .. Upvote set ^

Comment: This works fine on MacOS Sierra :-)

Answer (score 2):

RCDefaultApp replacement called SwiftDefaultApps

tested on Big Sur 11.2.3 on intel Mac mini

https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

[image]